# How would I add the timezone to a datetime.datetime object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a `datetime.datetime` object (`datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 11, 18, 0)`) and I would like to assign it a timezone using `pytz`. I know you can use `pytz` with a `datetime.datetime.now()` object (`datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))`) but how would I do it with a custom object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`localize` method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

```
import pytz
import datetime
la = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
now = la.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
print(repr(now))
```

yields

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 11, 21, 36, 2, 981916, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

---

`localize` is used to interpret timezone-unaware datetimes with respect to a timezone. The result is a timezone-aware datetime.
Note that some timezone-unaware datetimes, such as `datetime(2002, 10, 27, 1, 30, 00)`, are ambiguous in certain timezones. [Use the `is_dst` parameter](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime) to avoid the ambiguity.

`astimezone` is used to convert aware datetimes to other timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can assign timezone to `os.environ['TZ']` directly.

```
import os
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.now()

os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Los_Angeles'

print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: you should call `time.tzset()` after the TZ change. Also both setting TZ and using `tzset()` are Unix-specific.

Comment: This is a very simple but useful approach on Linux.  Python datetime is a nightmare no matter how you cut it.